# DATA ENCRYPTION 2048 RSA Algorithm using public key in mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

i want to encrypt a json data
{
"urc": "7718313198",
"umc": "101871",
"ak": "asdfgh123456",
"fname": "Biswajit",
"lname": "Dolui",
"email": "retailer001@giblvirtualmail.com",
"phno": "7718313198",
"pin": "712410"
}

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please note that SO is not a code writing service. Kindly edit your question and add the code that you have written so far and you are struggling with, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i could not encrypt long string in asp.net using rsa algorithm 2048
var csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);

```
        //how to get the private key
        var privKey = csp.ExportParameters(true);

        //and the public key ...
        var pubKey = csp.ExportParameters(false);

        //converting the public key into a string representation
        string pubKeyString;
        {
            //we need some buffer
            var sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            //we need a serializer
            var xs = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));
            //serialize the key into the stream
            xs.Serialize(sw, pubKey);
            //get the string from the stream
            pubKeyString = sw.ToString();
        }

        //converting it back
        {
            //get a stream from the string
            var sr = new System.IO.StringReader(pubKeyString);
            //we need a deserializer
            var xs = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));
            //get the object back from the stream
            pubKey = (RSAParameters)xs.Deserialize(sr);
        }

        //conversion for the private key is no black magic either ... omitted

        //we have a public key ... let's get a new csp and load that key
        csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        csp.ImportParameters(pubKey);

        //we need some data to encrypt
        var plainTextData = "{urc: 7718313198,umc: 101871,ak: asdfgh123456,fname: Biswajit,lname: Dolui,email: biswajitdoluicse@gmail.com,phno: 7718313198}";

        //for encryption, always handle bytes...
        var bytesPlainTextData = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainTextData);

        //apply pkcs#1.5 padding and encrypt our data 
        var bytesCypherText = csp.Encrypt(bytesPlainTextData, false);

        //we might want a string representation of our cypher text... base64 will do
        var cypherText = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesCypherText);
```

Comment: //apply pkcs#1.5 padding and encrypt our data 
        var bytesCypherText = csp.Encrypt(bytesPlainTextData, false);
Here i seen the problem,when i pass small string for encryption it is ok but when i pass long string for encryption then its not encrypted.